# How can I get HH format for hours in DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

When I invoke ToString method of DateTime I get the follow string

```
"17.05.2010 8:05:22".
```

Is there any other DateTime format where i can get the follow string

```
"17.05.2010 08:05:22"
```

with zero before the eight hours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
someDateInstance.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```